# Orchard and Route Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, orchardcms

An interesting one.

On a team of half a dozen developers, I am the only one experiencing the following problem so we are reasonably sure that it is something local to myself but we can't seem to track down what is causing it.

Using a Orchard based site, the default home page is overridden using a Route provider:

```
public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
        {
            return new[]{
                new RouteDescriptor{
                    Name = "Homepage",
                    Priority = 85,
                    Route = new Route(
                        "",
                        new RouteValueDictionary{
                            {"area", "Area"},
                            {"controller", "BingoGame"},
                            {"action", "BingoRealm" },
                            {"realm", "realmName" }
                        },
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary{
                            {"area", "Area"}
                        },
                        new MvcRouteHandler())
                },
                ...
```

However, once I log in to the application (where I expect to the be taken to the home page the following error occurs:

> No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
>
> **Source Error:**

```
Line 160:            public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) {
Line 161:                try {
Line 162:                    _httpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(result);
Line 163:                }
Line 164:                finally {
```

So here we have somewhere that establishes a route yet try to access that route and nothing is found.

As I mentioned, only myself is experiencing this particular error and we can think of nothing local to my machine that should be influencing this matter.

Solutions? Suggestions? Questions?

Comment: What happens if you copy the complete Orchard instance, including source, Settings.txt files and DB from one of your colleagues to yourself?

Comment: Is your setup *exactly* the same as your colleagues? I mean the features enabled, local webserver used, local domain name (if any) + other things @Piedone described.

Comment: Are you sure it is attempting to go to that route.Do you have any action filters on code that re-route you? If it only fails for you then it is either environment or data that you are consuming. 

Please check your orchard log to see if there are any outstanding error messages. I would suggest resolving these before further diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let people know: So it turns out someone had commented our error-handling module out of the recipe and forgotten to put it back in so it was trying to redirect to an error page that didn't exist over a problem we weren't seeing because our error reporting wasn't working properly at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few instances where this was failing. Here's something to try:

Try to stop the webserver instance and remove the `Dependencies` folder in `App_Data` and restart it afterwards. Sometimes Orchard refuses to load new assemblies after you've compiled in Visual Studio.

The problem occurs because assemblies get locked in the dependencies folder. Because the dev server/IIS Express are still running during compilation, the assemblies in the dependencies don't get replaced with new ones.

The faulty behavior can be fixed by either stopping the IIS express/Dev webserver and running the project again. If you want to be extra secure here, remove the dependencies folder.